# flashvars: how do I disable the progress bar?

Tags: flashvars

I'd like to disable the progress bar on a camtasia generated flash video presentation.

Here is the link to the http://forgottensecretsforabs.com/demo-page.html

I've tried adding/setting the following parameters but it doesn't work.

I thought controlbar=none would do it but the progress bar still appears.

Please help!